concentration inequality for function of dependent random variables, $F(Z_i)$, and $Z_i = Y + X_i$, where $X_i$ are iid. $X_i$ is independent of $Y$.
How to derive the concentration bound for such $F(Z_i)$, and $Z_i = Y + X_i$, where $X_i$ are iid random variables, $Y$ is a random variable, and $X_i$ is independent of $Y$.
I want something like this:
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\bigg|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in [N]} F(Z_i) - \mathbb{E}[F(Z_i)]\bigg| > \varepsilon\bigg\}.
$$
I have tried using conditioning like this,
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\Big\{\bigg|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in [N]} F(Z_i) - \mathbb{E}[F(Z_i)|Y]\bigg| > \varepsilon\Big\}\Big|Y\bigg\},
$$
but then I take expectation of both sides, I can only get
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\bigg|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in [N]} F(Z_i) - \mathbb{E}[F(Z_i)|Y]\bigg| > \varepsilon\bigg\},
$$
which is not what I want.

Conditions:
$F$ is Lipschitz continuous in $Z$, but not assumed linear, not assumed convex.
The distribution of $X_i$ satisfies transportation cost inequality with pamater $\gamma$, leading to the result of
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\bigg|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in [N]} F(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[F(X_i)]\bigg|> \varepsilon \bigg\} \leq 2 \exp\bigg(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\gamma L^2}\bigg),
$$
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $F$.

Questions:
Is there anything wrong in my using of conditioning? How can I get the result I desired.
Thank you so much for your help.

@DavideGiraudo Thank you, F is Lipschitz continuous in Z, but not linear, not convex

I guess in general there is not much that can be said... Are $Y$ and $X_i$ independent? Also if they are, the concentration cannot be better of the one of $Y$ around its mean, which will not improve as $N$ grow... If they are dependent anything could happen...

Ok, thanks for the clarification. Is there some independence between $Y$ and the sequence $(X_i)$?

@ECL Yes $Y$ and $X_i$  are independent. Sorry I forgot to add this information. I have added it now.

@DavideGiraudo Yes $Y$ and $X_i$  are independent. Sorry I forgot to add this information. I have added it now.

And what is it known about the concentration of the single $X_i$ and of $Y$? Like, are they bounded random variable? Are they subgaussian? Do they have bounded moments?

@ECL In my context, I used transportation cost, with the condition that the distribution of $X_i$ satisfies transportation cost inequality with pamater $\gamma$, leading to the result of $\mathbb{P}{|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i \in [N]} F(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[F(X_i)]|> \varepsilon } \leq 2 \exp(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\gamma L^2})$, where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $F$

@ECL Thank you for asking! I have added those information in the main text.
